# apply and boxcox function error in R

Tags: r, apply

I am having a problem with using the apply function when calling the boxcox function.

The dataset consists of 35 samples, 3 treatments across 2 days (some individuals are repeated across days but always within treatment group) with ~1000 measurements / dependent variables, I have included just 5 here (#1,2,4,7,9).

```
NUM day trt 1   2   4   7   9  
8145    7   L   0.986   0.423   0.86    0.648   2.031  
8169    7   L   1.013   0.512   1.157   0.633   0.55  
8201    7   L   0.236   6.144   0.604   1.759   1.181  
8212    7   L   0.455   0.707   0.693   0.972   0.615  
8168    7   L   1.261   0.618   1.138   0.943   0.868  
8193    7   L   1.754   0.273   1.224   0.719   0.895  
8145    13  L   1.257   0.36    1.505   0.729   0.735  
8169    13  L   1.549   0.577   1.53    0.771   1.116  
8201    13  L   0.489   0.378   0.842   1.538   1.676  
8212    13  L   0.991   0.34    1.03    1.157   1.076  
8168    13  L   1.355   0.391   1.416   0.953   1.479  
8193    13  L   1.029   0.308   1.027   0.902   1.934  
8214    7   C   1.224   0.298   1.113   1.445   0.218  
8139    7   C   1.277   0.554   1.443   0.895   0.74  
8151    7   C   1.312   2.025   1.197   0.675   0.791  
8160    7   C   1.555   0.405   1.432   0.826   0.501  
8196    7   C   0.938   0.717   0.917   0.801   1.462  
8213    7   C   0.835   1.863   0.942   1.967   0.739  
8139    13  C   0.958   0.275   1.273   1.351   0.842  
8151    13  C   0.864   0.517   0.98    1.368   1.865  
8160    13  C   1.516   0.895   1.318   0.551   0.779  
8239    13  C   1.071   0.194   0.955   1.87    0.68  
8196    13  C   1.299   0.594   1.14    0.877   1.873  
8213    13  C   1.601   0.733   1.375   0.738   1.273  
8231    7   H   1.401   0.483   1.001   1.052   0.548  
8232    7   H   1.292   0.574   1.634   0.641   0.464  
8219    7   H   0.785   0.396   0.886   0.903   1.734  
8177    7   H   0.525   0.252   0.563   0.914   1.174  
8143    7   H   1.398   0.266   0.947   0.94    0.781  
8219    13  H   0.903   6.225   1.109   1.218   1.073  
8143    13  H   1.086   0.435   1.4 0.922   0.925  
8167    13  H   0.83    0.574   1.09    1.338   1.563  
8231    13  H   1.498   0.482   1.375   0.855   0.719  
8232    13  H   1.055   0.811   0.887   0.606   0.634  
8177    13  H   0.857   1.324   0.954   1.635   0.675
```

I am attempting to run the boxcox function in the MASS package in R to assess if data needs to be transformed and if so to transform according to the lamda value with the maximum log likelihood (or rounding thereof).

```
linear.f=function(x){lm(x~day+trt+day*trt, data=data)}
linear.multiple=apply(data[,4:ncol(data)],2,linear.f)
```

works OK

and running the boxcox function individually also works OK

```
boxcox(lm(x~day+trt+day*trt,data=data))$x[which.max(boxcox(lm(x~day+trt+day*trt, data=data))$y)]
```

putting into function for apply:

```
lamda.f=function(x){boxcox(lm(x~day+trt+day*trt, data=data))$x[which.max(boxcox(lm(x~day+trt+day*trt, data=data))$y)]}
```

However, the problem arises when attempting to run the boxcox across all columns / dependent variables using apply:

```
lamda.multiple=apply(data[,4:ncol(data)],2,lamda.f)
```

error:

```
 Error in model.frame.default(formula = x ~ day + trt + day * trt, data = data,  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'x'
```

Am I doing something that is obviously incorrect  ? as the boxcox will work if its one by one on each column of data..

I've also tried this by using a for loop instead of apply but was unsuccessful

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not related to the `apply()` call. It has to do with the fact that you're using `x` in your formula, but the data set you're passing to `lm()` has no `x` column.

The `lm()` function is a little bit "lenient", perhaps inadvisably so. If a symbol within the given formula cannot be found in the given data set, then `lm()` allows it to bind to any variable that can be found in the closure environment chain of the formula. From https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/model.frame.html:

> All the variables in formula, subset and in ... are looked for first in data and then in the environment of formula (see the help for formula() for further details) and collected into a data frame.
>
> ...
>
> Only variables whose type is raw, logical, integer, real, complex or character can be included in a model frame: this includes classed variables such as factors (whose underlying type is integer), but excludes lists.

Now, actually, both your `linear.f()` and `lamda.f()` functions have a function parameter `x`, and this allows the `lm()` call to succeed, in *both* functions. IOW, when `lm()` runs inside these functions, the `x` fails to bind to any column in the given data set (`data`), but then binds to the function parameter in the closure environment of the formula (which is the evaluation environment of the current function evaluation). Thus, the `lm()` call succeeds.

To go into more detail: When a function is evaluated, its parameters are always stored in the evaluation environment that is created for that particular evaluation of that particular function. Since you've defined the formula literally inside the function, it closures around the current evaluation environment, and thus when `lm()` runs, after failing to bind to a column in the data set, the search for a target for the symbol `x` hits that environment first and binds to the function parameter entry in the environment.

I notice you indicated that the one-off top-level call of `lm()`+`boxcox()` succeeded. This is curious, since there's no function parameter to bind to. I can only guess that at the time you ran that line of code, you happened to have in the global environment a variable `x` which was valid for the model. If there isn't, then it should fail, since the `x` symbol in the formula has nothing to bind to in either the data set or the closure environment chain. Note that *`lm()`* should fail; I'm not even talking about `boxcox()` here:

```
if (exists('x')) rm(x); ## remove global x
lm(x~day+trt+day*trt,data=data);
## Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found
```

Now, at the time you ran your second apply call, we can probably guess that you had overwritten the global `x` variable with a list, which would result in the exact error message you got:

```
x <- list();
lm(x~day+trt+day*trt,data=data);
## Error in model.frame.default(formula = x ~ day + trt + day * trt, data = data,  :
##   invalid type (list) for variable 'x'
```

But there must be something else going on here. Recall how I pointed out that both `linear.f()` and `lamda.f()` have a function parameter `x`, and so `lm()` should be binding to that, and since that's a valid predictor vector, it should be succeeding.

It appears to me that `boxcox()` is calling `lm()` of its own accord, and somehow preventing the closure chain search from being done in that case. I believe I can prove that conjecture with the following code, which uses [IIFEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (originally a JavaScript term, but applicable to any language with first-class expressionizable functions, like R):

```
if (exists('x')) rm(x); ## remove global x
data2 <- data.frame(y=1:3); ## no x
(function(x) lm(y~x,data2))(1:3); ## x binds to function parameter
##
## Call:
## lm(formula = y ~ x, data = data2)
##
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)            x
##           0            1
##
(function(x) boxcox(lm(y~x,data2)))(1:3);
## Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found
traceback();
## 14: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
## 13: eval(predvars, data, env)
## 12: model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x, data = data2, drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
## 11: stats::model.frame(formula = y ~ x, data = data2, drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
## 10: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
## 9: eval(mf, parent.frame())
## 8: lm(formula = y ~ x, data = data2, y = TRUE, qr = TRUE)
## 7: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
## 6: eval(call, parent.frame())
## 5: update.default(object, y = TRUE, qr = TRUE, ...)
## 4: update(object, y = TRUE, qr = TRUE, ...)
## 3: boxcox.lm(lm(y ~ x, data2))
## 2: boxcox(lm(y ~ x, data2)) at #1
## 1: (function(x) boxcox(lm(y ~ x, data2)))(1:3)
```

As you can see, it appears that `boxcox()` is running `lm()`, but unlike the straight `lm()` call, fails to bind to the function parameter `x`, even though it should be able to, since the formula argument passed to `boxcox()` contains the closure environment pointer. We could chalk this up to a weakness in the `boxcox()` function, I suppose.

Anyway, with respect to a solution, a good approach would be to *not* depend on the closure environment system to resolve unbound formula symbols, and instead always ensure that the given data set contains columns for all symbols in the formula. Simple example:

```
data2 <- data.frame(y=1:3,x=10:12);
boxcox(lm(y~x,data2)); ## succeeds
```

This is not so simple in your case, however, because you have a dynamic outcome variable. A good approach would be supplement your data.frame with the outcome variable just before passing it to the `lm()` call, e.g. with `cbind(data,x)`.

Unfortunately, and surprisingly, I'm getting the following error:

```
lamda.f <- function(x) { data.x <- cbind(data,x); boxcox(lm(x~day+trt+day*trt,data=data.x))$x[which.max(boxcox(lm(x~day+trt+day*trt,data=data.x))$y)]; };
lamda.multiple <- apply(data[,4:ncol(data)],2,lamda.f);
## Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'data.x' not found
```

I even tried separating out the `lm()` call from the `boxcox()` call, in case `boxcox()` was doing some kind of crazy non-standard evaluation of its arguments, and thus trying to evaluate `data.x` in a context that would prevent binding with the `lamda.f()` evaluation environment:

```
lamda.f <- function(x) { data.x <- cbind(data,x); m <- lm(x~day+trt+day*trt,data=data.x); b <- boxcox(m); b$x[which.max(b$y)]; };
lamda.multiple <- apply(data[,4:ncol(data)],2,lamda.f);
## Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'data.x' not found
```

It looks to me like `boxcox()` is depending very heavily on the global environment. Running `boxcox()` from inside a function scope and depending on any local variables just breaks it. I suspect it's examining the call stored on the model object (e.g. `m$call`) and trying to read the symbols directly. In any case, this is just really weird.

I think you can solve this by storing the supplemented data.frame in the global environment and ensuring it exists there at the moment `boxcox()` runs. You can use the superassignment operator for this:

```
lamda.f <- function(x) { data.x <<- cbind(data,x); m <- lm(x~day+trt+day*trt,data=data.x); b <- boxcox(m); b$x[which.max(b$y)]; };
lamda.multiple <- apply(data[,4:ncol(data)],2,lamda.f);
lamda.multiple;
##         X1         X2         X4         X7         X9
##  1.2323232 -0.6666667  0.7474747 -0.6666667  0.2222222
```